# How to find the number of keys in between rows that fit a certain criteria?

Tags: mysql

```
mytable
+------+------+
|id    |Yes/No|
+------+------+
|joe   |Yes   |
+------+------+
|bob   |No    |
+------+------+
|mike  |No    |
+------+------+
|bill  |Yes   |
+------+------+
|tim   |No    |
+------+------+
|dan   |No    |
+------+------+
|pete  |No    |
+------+------+
|jim   |No    |
+------+------+
|jon   |Yes   |
+------+------+
```

I want a query to select any two "Yes" rows with only "No" rows in between them, and then order them by the number of "No" rows, in descending order. So it should return

```
|bill, jon | 4 |
+----------+---+
|joe, bill | 2 |
+----------+---+
```

EDIT: mytable is ordered by the people's birthdays, which are stored in another table:

```
birthdays
+------+------+-------+-----+
|name  | year | month | day | 
+------+------+-------+-----+
|bill  | 2000 | 2     | 9   |
+------+------+-------+-----+
|bob   | 2000 | 1     | 3   |
+------+------+-------+-----+
|dan   | 2000 | 3     | 6   |
+------+------+-------+-----+
|mike  | 2000 | 2     | 7   |
+------+------+-------+-----+
|jim   | 2000 | 9     | 20  |
+------+------+-------+-----+
|joe   | 1999 | 5     | 4   |
+------+------+-------+-----+
|jon   | 2000 | 10    | 9   |
+------+------+-------+-----+
|pete  | 2000 | 8     | 6   |
+------+------+-------+-----+
|tim   | 2000 | 2     | 15  |
+------+------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have added another table

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `year`, `month`, `day`) rn
             FROM mytable t1
             JOIN birthdays t2 ON t1.id = t2.name)
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', t1.id, t2.id) names,
       t2.rn - t1.rn - 1 amount
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2
WHERE t1.Yes_or_No = 'Yes'
  AND t2.Yes_or_No = 'Yes'
  AND t2.rn > t1.rn
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM cte t3
                  WHERE t3.Yes_or_No = 'Yes'
                    AND t2.rn > t3.rn
                    AND t3.rn > t1.rn);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2f24d932d9b406a6052121b4f2a6e1e)